# What are the possible values for DocuSign account time zone from DocuSign Connect update?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign Connect/DocuSign Event Notifications to update DocuSign envelope/recipient statuses. I have written a .net application that parses an XML posted by Connect/Event notifications to update the statuses. Since each of my client's DocuSign account lies in a different time zone, I retrieve time zone of each of my client's DocuSign account from Connect update and my .net application adds offset based upon the time zone to update the statuses.

I need to know all possible values of DocuSign account time zone that I can retrieve from XML posted by Connect/Event notifications as the time zone values in DocuSign account are different than the time zone values that I get from Connect updates.

For example, if the time zone set in the DocuSign account is "Pacific Time(US & Canada)",the time zone that I get from Connect/Event notifications is "Pacific Standard Time".

Is there is a list of all possible values of Time zone that DocuSign Connect process posts?

Answer (score 3):

Connect will use your **Time Zone used for API** for almost all of the timestamps.

In **Features**, Set **Time Zone used for API**:

[image]

The correct Time Zone will be used in your Connect XML:

[image]

There are very few time entries in Connect that do use UTC and they are identified with a `Z`.

Example: `2014-07-24T18:09:14.9430000Z`

This should be manually converted by your listener to the approperiate time zone.