# Completed event notification - date time zone

Tags: docusignapi

For webhook event notifications, the completed event in particular, will the delivered and signed dates always be in PST or will they vary based on the server the user's base url points at or their account? I don't see that mentioned anywhere in documentation and it's impossible to tell from a demo account.

Of note:
1) We are not using Connect, just redirect url(s) on our integrator key that are added to envelope definition's envelope notification properties.
2) We are supporting multiple clients, each with their own DocuSign account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the possible values for DocuSign account time zone from DocuSign Connect update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937604/what-are-the-possible-values-for-docusign-account-time-zone-from-docusign-connec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates in the event notification will be in the Timezone that is set in your account settings. This will be applicable to all the envelopes sent from your account.

You can go to the Docusign Admin page and manage your account settings.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24941152/1219543) for more information.

EDIT: 
You can set the property **includeTimeZone** in your [eventNotification](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definitions--eventNotification). The envelope’s time zone information will then be included in the webhook messages.

Comment: The account won't be ours. That's why I have the question. The account on the envelope will be one of our client's docusign accounts run through our integrator key using oauth code grant using a callback URL on the event notification on the envelope (not using connect). Are you saying that regardless of our client's docusign account settings, the timezone of our integrator account will be used?

Comment: You can set the property **includeTimeZone** in your [eventNotification](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definitions--eventNotification). The envelope’s time zone information is included in the webhook messages.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @PraveenReddy
About eventNotification Webhooks

The webhook sends a Xml Payload to the endpoint,
will it sent a json payload if I set useSoapInterface to false in EventNotification configuration added while creating an envelop.
Also I am a little confused that what should be my requestObject structure in the endpoint which I configured for eventNotification Webhooks.