# Event notification time zone

Tags: docusignapi

I am a signer and sender of a document. The time zone configured under Regional Settings in Admin and My Preferences is Mountain Time but the time zone from the event notification is Pacific Time with an offset of -7 (Mountain Time).

The documentation states:

> Date Signed field: The time zone and date/time format information shown in >Date fields and form data in the signing user interface and PDF documents >depends on the signer:
>
> If the signer has a DocuSign account, then the signer's time zone and the >sender's date/time format settings are used for the information. If the >sender’s account does not allow users to set their own date/time format, then >the date/time format setting for the account is used. Note: By Default, all >signer accounts are set to a default of PST for the time zone.

There is no 'time zone' under Signing Settings.

Expecting `<TimeZone>Mountain Standard Time</TimeZone>` but receiving `<TimeZone>Pacific Standard Time</TimeZone>`

EDIT: As a separate but related question: Is the time zone shown in the event notification the time zone specified in the account settings? This post says it is [Completed event notification - date time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004980/completed-event-notification-date-time-zone) but that is 2 years old now so just wanted to be sure.

Comment: What API do you call when you get back the wrong timezone?

Comment: `POST /v2/accounts/{account id}/envelopes`

Comment: this is an API to create an envelope, I Can't find in the json that it returns a timezone. can you share the entire json you get back?

Comment: I'm creating an envelope in order to get the document PDF returned along with the envelope event statuses from the DocuSign event notification. I'm including our callback URL in that POST for DS to post to. I'm viewing the XML response payload in Connect. That is where I see the time zone issue.

Comment: Edited my post regarding additional time zone question.

Comment: and you used includeTimeZone in the request for the event notification?

Comment: Yes. It equals "true".

Comment: ok, one other question - the timezone, did you set it in admin for the entire account, or under preferences for the user? (or both)?

Comment: Currently, I have it set under admin only. I tried with preferences too and both but all result in the same.

Comment: are you using a developer sandbox (demo) account? If you send me the details - I can try to help. You can email me at inbar.gazit@docusign.com

Comment: Thank you. I have emailed you.

Comment: ok, hope this is now resolved for you?

Comment: yes. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: great. would you mind marking this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DocuSign Connect timezone passed is a legacy setting and in order to change it you'll need to contact the DocuSign Developer Support. Thanks.